# Loaded assembly into AppDomain but getting Could not load file or assembly exception

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I am trying to dynamically load some assemblies like this:

```
using (var svc = new MyClient()) // MyClient is proxy to a WCF service
{
    var bytecode = svc.GetAssembly();
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytecode);
    var dependencies = svc.GetDependencies();
    foreach (var dependency in dependencies)
    {
        Assembly.Load(dependency.Bytecode);
        Console.WriteLine("loaded {0}", asm.FullName);
    }
    var type = assembly.GetExportedTypes().First();
    var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    var obj = ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);    // get an exception here
}
```

However, I get an exception when ctor is invoked, and CLR tries to load dependent assemblies. I have loaded the dependencies into the app domain in the for loop. How can I fix this exception?

```
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at MyClass.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\Client\Program.cs:line 25
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       HResult=-2147024894
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Asm2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       Source=Asm1
       FileName=Asm2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = mymachine\me
LOG: DisplayName = Asm2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///f:/Client/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: f:\Client.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///f:/Client/bin/Debug/Asm2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///f:/Client/bin/Debug/Asm2/Asm2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///f:/Client/bin/Debug/Asm2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///f:/Client/bin/Debug/Asm2/Asm2.EXE.

       StackTrace:
            at MyNamespace.MyClass..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: The stack trace states that Asm2 is missing.  Can you check that the Asm2 assembly is in this dir: f:/Client/bin/Debug/

Comment: What are you trying to do? I have written a number of apps that dynamically load assemblies and instantiate types.  This seems to clearly be a dependency issue, where is Asm2 relative to the project loading it.

Comment: Asm2 is not there in that directory. I have already loaded it into the app domain in the for loop. also verified using Console.WriteLine. the CLR should bind against the already loaded assembly instead of searching the file system. This is what I want to accomplish, and am asking.

Comment: I think you should copy it there to ensure that is the current problem and then work backwards to see why its trying to load it "again".  Is it perhaps looking for an older version of Asm (1.0.0.0)??

Comment: Using Assembly.Load(byte[])?  The CLR should *not* bind against that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved a similar problem by handling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;

private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == args.Name);
}
```

This requires that all dependencies are already loaded.

Comment: excellent! made this modification:
private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName == args.Name).SingleOrDefault();
        }